# How do I insert leading zeros in Ruby dateTime minute

Tags: ruby, datetime, xml-rpc, datetime-format

I have a script which calls an API. The API returns a dateTime.iso8601 object. I can't seem to figure out how to get the leading zero on the minutes, though.

I've looked at other questions here that say to use strftime, but that throws `undefined method 'strftime'`.

I've tried the following:

```
systems.each do |system|
    time = system["last_checkin"].strftime('%H:$M')
    print "#{system['name']} #{time}\n"
end

systems.each do |system|
    time = system["last_checkin"]
    hour = time.strftime('%H')
    min = time.strftime('%m')
    print "#{system['name']} #{hour}:#{min}\n"
end
```

And a few others that I no longer recall.

How should I be approaching this?

Comment: what is the output of ```system["last_checkin"].class``` ?

Comment: `opensuse-12-3:ruby:8688 $ ./sat-inactive.rb 
XMLRPC::DateTime
XMLRPC::DateTime
XMLRPC::DateTime
XMLRPC::DateTime
XMLRPC::DateTime
XMLRPC::DateTime
XMLRPC::DateTime
XMLRPC::DateTime
XMLRPC::DateTime
XMLRPC::DateTime` I guess several items of that class within the object?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for [`strftime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime)?

Comment: so XMLRPC::DateTime has no strftime http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/xmlrpc/rdoc/XMLRPC/DateTime.html

Comment: I did notice that, yes. If I just use time.min to extract the minute stamp I only get one digit without the leading zero. How do I get that leading zero in there? Is time.min a simply a string which can then be manipulated as such?

Comment: @theillien what does 'leading zero' refer to, you could add what you have tried with the links provided and what you are expecting, that would make it easier for you to get an answer

Comment: min is a ```Fixnum```
```
irb(main):012:0> XMLRPC::DateTime.new(2014,02,30,16,32,12).min.class
=> Fixnum
```
you can always convert that number to a ```String``` by doing ```some_fixnum.to_s```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
system["last_checkin"].to_time.strftime('%H:%M')
```

which will convert it to a [Time](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Time.html)(which has the date) and then you can use strftime to get the format you want

Comment: Took it a step further and used `%R` instead. Thanks for leading me to the proper documentation.

Comment: np, you can always use ```.class``` or ```.inspect``` (inspect shows more info on complex items) which exists on all objects for info and then run to [ruby-doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org),[api-doc](http://apidock.com/ruby) or [yard](http://rdoc.info) for options

Answer (score 0):

After digging around and piecing together the snippets of information I have and have received I was finally able to find something that made sense to me.

I simply formatted the time.min string:

```
min = "%02d" % time.min
```

I also added `12` to time.hour to get the 24-hour format.

```
systems.each do |system|
    time = system["last_checkin"]
    hour = time.hour + 12
    min = "%02d" % time.min
    print "#{system['name']} #{hour}:#{min}\n"
end
```

I imagine there is a more concise way to do this, but being new to Ruby, I'm content with this.

EDIT:
While writing up my solution [jtzero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/237129/jtzero) posted the more concise way I was expecting would be possible.